# How can I use Mockito's verify on code running in Looper.getMainLooper?

Tags: java, android, mockito, powermockito

Given this block of code:

```
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            _view.displaySomething();
        }
    });
```

I want to call Mockito's `verify(_view).displaySomething()` in my unit test, but I receive the following error:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Method getMainLooper in android.os.Looper not mocked.`

Can someone point me to what I could do to achieve this without error?

Comment: Where `_view` is assigned with a value (reference object)?

Comment: Have you already investigated the use of [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/)? It's designed to provide implementations of Android's system that are designed for unit tests. If you haven't, I'll follow up with a full answer.

Comment: I've not tried Roboelectric.

Comment: i recommend you to use @RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is common problem with testing Android-related classes, they don't have default implementations when running pure JUnit test.

You have two possibilities:

- **seperate your logic from Android framework** - then you can test everything flawlessly. It is always a good idea to separate framework from your logic. This is also one of the main purposes of all popular architectures, be it MVP, MVVM or MVI
- **run your test as [Android Instrumented Test](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests) (with Android JUnit runner)** - then classes from Android sdk simply work as expected. Drawback - you must use device or emulator and your tests are slower.